# Spyder 4 doesn't launch

Tags: kubuntu, python, spyder

I have installed spyder 4 on my kubuntu but when I try to launch it, it doesn't start and in the konsole, I got this :

```
File "/usr/bin/spyder", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('spyder==4.2.1', 'gui_scripts', 'spyder')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/start.py", line 213, in main
    mainwindow.main(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3624, in main
    mainwindow = create_window(app, splash, options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 3482, in create_window
    main.setup()
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/app/mainwindow.py", line 803, in setup
    self.completions = CompletionManager(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/plugin.py", line 97, in __init__
    plugin_client = Plugin(self.main)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/kite/plugin.py", line 50, in __init__
    self.installer = KiteInstallerDialog(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/kite/widgets/install.py", line 287, in __init__
    self._integration_widget = KiteIntegrationInfo(self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/spyder/plugins/completion/kite/widgets/install.py", line 58, in __init__
    image = image.scaled(image_width, image_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio,
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  scaled(self, int, int, aspectRatioMode: Qt.AspectRatioMode = Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, transformMode: Qt.TransformationMode = Qt.FastTransformation): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
  scaled(self, QSize, aspectRatioMode: Qt.AspectRatioMode = Qt.IgnoreAspectRatio, transformMode: Qt.TransformationMode = Qt.FastTransformation): argument 1 has unexpected type 'float'
```

Any idea on what's happening ?

I'm new to ubuntu so I really don't have a clue...

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: It appears to be this bug, https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/18919, for which that issue provides a solution; the error being in a bad package?